# echo specific value with specific id in unknown rows (foreach loop)

Tags: php, json, foreach

ive got a new question for a new project. At the moment im creating a new website which tracks multiple stats of gaming characters in WoW, so i worked with the blizzard api and ask for informations out of a json-file. The Problem i have at the moment: I need to get a specific value out of this [JSON-File](https://eu.api.blizzard.com/profile/wow/character/destromath/kimjonghoj/achievements/statistics?namespace=profile-eu&locale=de_DE&access_token=USpHyc8AMt8eiT8pFCLeoVLF3xS1ecKl8h).
I need the value of "quantity" with the id 370 which is in an variable row-number. For that i work with a foreach loop like that:

```
        foreach($decodearena3['statistics'][8]['sub_categories'][0]['statistics'] as $arenastats) {
        if ($arenastats['id'] == "370") {
        echo $arenastats['quantity'];
          }
```

The problem is: The row [8] is variable, so it also can be any number depending a on a characters experience. In this row is an ID (21) so i guess i should do a foreach to find that ID and then finally the row. After that i guess i need to make a new foreach to then find the ID 370 in the other unknown row, right?

I Hope you understand what i mean, cuz my english skills are not the best. Maybe the Screenshot explains it better :).

The Screenshot which explains what im looking for:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZhaS.png)

Comment: This is basically the same question you asked already yesterday: [Foreach Loop JSON get specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60719754/foreach-loop-json-get-specific-value)

Comment: Nah, not really. This was my problem before this came. Now i need to find an unknown row number in an unknown row number :/. Feels really complicated to get that logic here. Look at the Screenshot i added please.

Comment: Then explain how this is actually, _significantly_ different, please. Yesterday you had `$decodeachieve['achievements'][2207]['id']`, and said you wanted to look for something in that, but the `2207` part wasn’t static. So, obvious response - _loop over_ `$decodeachieve['achievements']` first then. I don’t see how _anything_ about this scenario here would be significantly different now?

Comment: Yeah, this was one which wasnt static, now i need to get in the first unknown..and then find the second unknown in the first unknown. So i need to make a foreach in a foreach?! Maybe i just dont get it. :( thought the whole day about that to get it right.

Comment: If you want to loop over _all_ entries on multiple levels, then you need multiple loops, correctly nested into each other. So loop over `$decodearena3['statistics']`, your “item” in that loop will then be the sub-structure beginning at the `sub_categories` key. You want to loop over `statistics` inside the first element of that array again.

Comment: Okay, i will try that..thank you!

Comment: look at my post. i added it. sth like that? it doesnt work..but i need to find the logic. im new to php and getting the logic sometimes feels a little hard to get for me. this is my first learning project.

Comment: When you use `foreach ($something as $value)`, then within the loop you're working with `$value`. So a nested foreach would need to reference *that*: `foreach ($value as $whatever)`. The next one works with `$whatever` and so on. Additionally, never name your individual values (the part after `as`) the same as the original variable you're working with, like you did here: `foreach($pvpid['statistics'] as $pvpid)`. At the end of the loop, your original `$pvpid` will be overwritten with the last value from the loop.

Comment: ^this. really thanks for helping me to understand this nested thing. now it works and im happy! learned a lot new stuff. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

This comment from @El_Vanja helped me to get the solution: 
When you use foreach ($something as $value), then within the loop you're working with $value. So a nested foreach would need to reference that: foreach ($value as $whatever). The next one works with $whatever and so on. Additionally, never name your individual values (the part after as) the same as the original variable you're working with, like you did here: foreach($pvpid['statistics'] as $pvpid). At the end of the loop, your original $pvpid will be overwritten with the last value from the loop. – El_Vanja

```
        foreach($decodearena3['statistics'] as $staticsid) {
            if ($staticsid['id'] == "21") {
                foreach($staticsid['sub_categories'][0]['statistics'] as $ratedarenaid) {
                    if ($ratedarenaid['id'] == "370") {
                        echo $ratedarenaid['quantity'];
             }
            }
           } 
          }
```

Thank you!